# Вертикальное мега меню

Tags: меню, css

Добрый день! Имеется вертикальное меню, с выпадающим контейнером, в котором множество под категорий. Вообщем такая проблема, когда увеличиваешь масштаб окна браузера, то списки начинают сдвигаться вверх, то есть, как я понял, то что им места не хватает внизу (хотя должно включиться авто пролистывание вниз). Ширина и высота выпадающего контейнера задана, так же задал `top: 82px;` это для того, чтобы списки выпадали с одной высоты.

Comment: А вопрос где? Где исходники, примеры?

Comment: Вообщем такая проблема, когда увеличиваешь масштаб окна браузера, то списки начинают сдвигаться вверх, как исправить? Вот вопрос! Куда можно код залить? Уж слишком длинный получится здесь.

Comment: @DimasikYES, код можно выложить на jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @likerRr, Вот http://jsfiddle.net/a75GY/2/.

Comment: я бы в таком случае не переживал и сделал позицию fixed http://jsfiddle.net/a75GY/3/ 163 строка

Comment: @eicto, Спасибо. Пока подожду еще, может кто-то еще подскажет, что-нибудь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделал позицию fixed и задал top http://jsfiddle.net/a75GY/3/ 163 строка, как посоветовал [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto)